# How EOF is encountered by sort program?

Tags: c, pipe

On command line, `sort` program can be given inputs with `^D` as end of input

```
$ sort
xyz
def
abc
^D

abc
def
xyz
```

---

Below program is using pipe to perform the same,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(void){

  FILE *pipeFP;
  char *str[3] = {"xyz\n", "def\n", "abc\n"};

  if((pipeFP = popen("sort", "w")) == NULL){
    perror("popen error");
    exit(1);
  }

  /*
     popen() performs the following:
     1) In parent process, calls pipe() for creating two descriptors, read descriptor is closed, write descriptor is converted to FILE type stream
     2) In parent process, calls fork() to create child process and execs with sort program.
     3) In child process, write end descriptor is closed, read descriptor is dup2 to stdin
  */


  /* Sending string list to sort program*/
  fputs(str[0], pipeFP);
  fputs(str[1], pipeFP);
  fputs(str[2], pipeFP);

  pclose(pipeFP);
}
```

---

In this program, `^D` is not sent to `sort` child process, How does `sort` realize the end of input?

Comment: You are closing the pipe pretty much terminating the input stream....

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Do you mean, sort actually gives the output after closing the write stream(`pclose(pipeFP)`)

Comment: You can easily verify it...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I verified at htttp://www.onlinegdb.com/. I dont have linux vm. `gdb` is not working in cygwin. As output stream is closed, automatically read descriptor of `sort` program is closed

Comment: Add some prints then.

Comment: `sort` cannot output anything until it knows which line to output first, and it cannot know that until it has read all the input.

Comment: Also, the `^D` from the terminal is never sent to the `sort` process - it only sees an `EOF` on its standard input stream. The only difference from `sort`'s point of view is that its standard input is coming from a pipe, rather than from a terminal. There are ways to test if the standard input is coming from a terminal, but I doubt that `sort` cares where it comes from.

Comment: @IanAbbott  In my program, input is coming from standard input(`stdin`), as well,

Comment: @overexchange: But your program above does not read its standard input. The `sort` program run by `popen` reads its own standard input, which comes from one end of the pipe.

Comment: It's enlightening to know how an "end-of-file" is represented. It occurs when the `read()` system call is trying to read a non-zero number of bytes and returns 0 - the return value 0 indicates "end-of-file". In the case of the pipe, this occurs when the "write" side of the pipe has been closed and all data left in the pipe has been read, the next `read()` will return 0. In the case where input is coming from a TTY in "canonical mode" (line-by-line input mode), a CTRL-D at the start of a line causes the next `read()` to return 0, which the program sees as an "end-of-file".

Answer (score 0):

[From the pclose man page](http://man.cx/pclose):

> The `pclose()` function shall close a stream that was opened by `popen()`,
>   wait for the command to terminate, and return the termination status
>   of the process that was running the command language interpreter.

The `sort` program does something similar to this (in pseudo code):

```
buffer = []
while true {
    line = readline(stdin)
    if line == EOF {
        break
    }
    buffer += line
}
print(sort_lines(buffer))
exit
```

When you call `pclose(pipeFP)` it closes the `sort`'s `stdin` pipe (which causes `sort` to read an EOF) then waits until `sort` exits.